# Filling HTML table with MySQL data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to fill a table in HTML with data from a MySQL table. I watched many videos about it and I've made it step by step like them, but still, the output in the table is not the expected output from the database, it's like this:

```
" . $row['EXAMPLE'] . "
```

Before the table starts, there is also this code printed down:

```
query($sql); while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "" } mysqli_close($con) ?>
```

This is my PHP code in the HTML doc:

```
<?php  

$sql = "SELECT EXAMPLE, EXAMPLE2 FROM EXAMPLE";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo  "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['EXAMPLE'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['EXAMPLE2'] . "</td>
        </tr>"

}
```

In the head of the doc is the following code:

```
<?php

$host = "example";
$username = "example";
$password = "example";
$database = "example";

$con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

?>
```

Comment: Php code needs to be in a .php file and served via a webserver which has php installed. If you're seeing raw php code in your page then it's likely one or more of these conditions has not been met

Comment: You missed a `;` after the echo line. Also, is your file a PHP file?

Comment: Your code is missing `<table>` tags and you should escape your raw data like this: `echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['EXAMPLE']) . "</td>\n";`. If you don't escape it you could break your HTML (ex: `</body>`) or have security issues (ex: `<script>alert('XSS')</script>` or `<a onclick="alert('XSS')">Click here</a>`).